# load new infowindow on value change

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I am able to create 4 infowindow as per the response now the task is to change the value within the infowindow on click of a button that is within the infowindow and close it. The value successfully changes but when the infowindow is opened again the earlier instance of infowindow is loaded and not the new one.

Im creating the marker and infowindow in $.each loop and while debug iv figured that whenever the marker is clicked it goes to this $.each loop where the listener is attached and has old values. The problem is opening a new infowindow instance on click and not have it loaded frem the each loop.

```
$.each(obj,function(i,value){
   var eventmarker = new google.maps.Marker;
   eventmarker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(value.Latitude),parseFloat(value.Longitude)));
   eventmarker.setMap(mymapper);
   listener =  eventmarker.addListener("click",function(){
   infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
   var content = value;
   infoWindow.setContent(content);
   infoWindow.open(mymapper,eventmarker);
});
```

Comment: Can you post some code? If  I remember correctly you will can have only one instance of infowindow.

Comment: have shared the code. the map is created outside the $.each and the infowindow content has a button on click of which the value changes successfully but when i close the window and click on marker again it goes into the $.each and opens the same old infowindow

Answer (score 0):

Try creating `infoWindow` outside of each loop like this,and put code for creating marker inside closure.
I made working fiddle for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/6973rbL8/

```
function initialize() {

 var myOptions = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(16,15),
     zoom: 4,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };
var myMapper = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("default"),
              myOptions);
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var obj=[{Latitude:16,Longitude:15},{Latitude:16,Longitude:14},
 {Latitude:16,Longitude:1}]

 $.each(obj,function(i,value){
      var eventmarker = new google.maps.Marker;
      eventmarker.setPosition(new  
 google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(value.Latitude),parseFloat(value.Longitude)));
 eventmarker.setMap(mymapper);
 });


 }
```

Comment: no Vlado iv tried that it doesnt work. i.e i get the same result

Comment: Thanks Vlado. but yet the same. The issue that i see is that the eventlistner is within the $.each loop and the infowindow is using the data(content) of the each loop iteration which is not updated hence always the nonupdated data is seen.

Comment: Then show more code. Where is content variable defined. What is expectes behavior (result)?

Comment: No im wrong thats not the case. i tried updating the contents field after click of button manually but it doesnt check that i.e it loads the instance created during first time of click event having the old value. The content values im creating dynamically within the for each with the help of the iteration of the each loop and having all 4 response values placed into infowindow iteratively

Comment: I have a field which is to be subtracted on each click of that button. say while loading the value was 10 on 1st time of clicking it should be 9 then 8, 7 & so on till 6. What is happening is if i dont close the infowindow with the close button the values change on each click but when i close the infowindow using the close button or through its close() method and reopen by clicking on marker im getting the first value i.e 10 and only after clicking the button again do i see the latest value with 1 subtracted i.e 5

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the effort Vlado really appreciate it.
Im able to get desired result by placing the code of infowindow in a new function and calling that function in the $.each loop. The function takes three params value(content),marker and map. within the func creating the content on each call ensures that the new content is set to the infowindow which i declared globally outside the each loop. So on every click of button im just updating the value in the response global variable and using this new val in the function to update infowindow.